# ToolkitScriptManager is not a known element

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a website in which I am using the AJAX Accordion Pane. In order to fully use the `RequireOpenedPane="False"` I need to have the `ToolkitScriptManager` added to the site.

I understand all of this but there's an issue. Visual Studio 2012 says the `ToolkitScriptManager is not a known element`

I have

`<add tagPrefix="asp" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />`

in the web.config file, and

`<asp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" CssClass="accordion" SelectedIndex="-1" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader" HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected" ContentCssClass="accordionContent" RequireOpenedPane="False" FramesPerSecond="25" Width="820px" >`

works with no errors. But

`<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>`

does not.

Here's the funny thing, if I remove the `ToolkitScriptManager` from the page, it'll load the Accordion, however, not all functionality will be working (for example, clicking an accordion header does not select the header, it just expands the header, but does not show as "Selected").

The page DOES have a MasterPage as well, the ToolkitScriptManager is inside the ContentPlaceHolder for the body. (it's actually right above the Accordion control). Why is this doing this, and how can I fix it?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="page.aspx.cs" Inherits="page" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderContent" runat="server">
 </asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MenuContent" runat="server">
 </asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h1 align="center">Classes</h1>
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" CssClass="accordion" SelectedIndex="-1" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader" HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected" ContentCssClass="accordionContent" RequireOpenedPane="False" FramesPerSecond="25" Width="820px" >
    <Panes>
        <asp:AccordionPane runat="server" ID="AccordionPane0">`
```

Answer (score 4):

Found solution:

Apparently the AjaxControlToolkit obtained from using the NuGet installer on Visual Studio 2010 does NOT have the ToolkitScriptManager. I had to remove the DLL installed from NuGet and install my own DLL which did include the ToolkitScriptManager.

I'm not sure why the NuGet version does not contain the ToolkitScriptManager.

Answer (score 0):

On top of your solution user1760784, others may ALSO need to setup IIS first and import their app in. Once the app is fully setup in IIS then try to run it. It should work. With this process done my issue was resolved. 
Please note this is true for both test IIS and live/production IIS. Although as we all know it's always safer to test off live boxes.

Why does it only resolve when testing on IIS?
I don't really know. However I believe it could because of http/browser issues. Maybe you smarter folks can let us know on this point.

Enjoy!